# Show that three vectors are collinear...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ be three points, or vectors, in $\mathbb{R}^2$; suppose that $v_2 \ne v_3$. Show that these points span the same subspace (i.e., are collinear) provided that $v_1-v_2 = c (v_2-v_3)$ for some number $c$.

There are some very helpful theorems that would make this problem much easier, but since we have not learned them in class yet, the professor has instructed that we cannot use them. We must use the tools that we have learned to solve this problem - like linear combination, span, subspace, etc. With that said, not sure how to go about doing this problem. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

### HINT

Assume the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{v_1} &= \left( a_1,\ b_1 \right) \tag{call it point P} \\
\vec{v_2} &= \left( a_2,\ b_2 \right) \tag{call it point Q} \\
\vec{v_3} &= \left( a_3,\ b_3 \right) \tag{call it point R}
\end{align}
$$

Now, find the slopes of line $ PQ $ and $ QR $ and compare it with the slope of line $ PR $.

If you're still unsure about their collinearity, the point $ Q $ is common in both of them.

Comment: hjpotter92, since it is in R^2, do only need a and b? Also should I represent the equation as an augment matrix and row reduce, finding a value for c?

Comment: @Cormano You don't need to find $ c $. And yes, the vectors will be reduced to $ \mathbb{R^2} $.

Comment: So I've found the slopes of PQ, QR, and PR. Nothing stands out to me. Another hint?

Comment: @Cormano Use the given relation: $ v_1-v_2 = c (v_2-v_3) $ in terms of $ a $ and $ b $. This will give you that the slopes of $ PQ $, $ QR $ and $ PR $ are the same and independent of $ c $. Now, think geometrically. If the slopes are equal, then the lines have to be either parallel or collinear. Since the point $ Q $ is common, they __have to be__ collinear.

Comment: I am sorry to be bother, hjpotter92. I've found the slopes. Slope of PQ: (b2-b1)/(a2-a1). QR: (b3-b2)/(a3-a2). PR:(b3-b1)/(a3-a1). I don't see how they are all the same slope.

Comment: @Cormano $ b_2 - b_1 = c \left( b_3 - b_2 \right) $. Use the same for $a_i$s

Comment: Ah, I see. Solve both equations in terms of c. Then, substitution one equation into the other through the relation c. Then, observe that the slopes are equal and compare them to PR.

Comment: I do have one question, though. Why is it allowed to do the equation in terms of a separately from be? If I were to use the given equation and used vector operations would I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You could show that one of them in in the span of the other two:

$$v_1 - v_2 = c(v_2 - v_3) = c v_2 - c v_3 \implies v_1 = (1 + c) v_2 + (-c) v_3 \in \operatorname{span}(v_2, v_3).$$

Comment: Is that sufficient to show that they are all collinear?

Answer (score 0):

Call $d=(d_1,d_2)=v_3-v_1$ and $d'=(d_1',d_2')=v_3-v_2$. Now convince yourself by an easy computation that
$$\exists\, c\in \mathbb R\colon c\cdot d'=d\iff d_1d_2'=d_1'd_2.$$
(It's crucial anyhow that $d'\neq0$.)